# Trouble installing PySide on Mac

Tags: python, pyside

I have been having a lot of trouble installing PySide. I installed Qt with brew install qt as suggested in this tutorial: pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/macosx.html.

My Mac is updated to High Sierra 10.13.3. When I run pip install -U Pyside, I get the following printout:

```
  Failed building wheel for Pyside
  Running setup.py clean for Pyside
Failed to build Pyside
Installing collected packages: Pyside
  Running setup.py install for Pyside ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-build-HTn1Jd/Pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-nRGV6n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Removing /private/var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-build-HTn1Jd/Pyside/pyside_package
    running install
    running build
    Python architecture is 64bit
    error: Failed to find qmake. Please specify the path to qmake with --qmake parameter.
```

Command

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-build-HTn1Jd/Pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-nRGV6n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4x/bkrfh91103936h2x82l9x_480000gn/T/pip-build-HTn1Jd/Pyside/
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: First, are you sure you want to install `PySide` for the builtin Python 2.7?

Comment: Second, have you installed Qt? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: Yeah, I've installed Qt. Here's the tutorial I followed: http://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/macosx.html

Comment: Not sure if I want to install PySide for the builtin... sorry I don't know much about it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess the first question is, do you want to use Python 2.7 (8 years old at this point, and going out of support for good in less than 2 years), or 3.6?

Comment: While we're at it, do you really want to use PySide (4 years since the last update, doesn't support current Qt or Python) instead of PySide2 or PyQt? There are good reasons for that (PyQt licensing and Nokia support, PySide2 not being in 1.0 state yet…), but it does mean you're stuck with old versions forever, so if those reasons don't apply, it may not be the right choice.

Comment: Finally, you should edit your question to put the tutorial link there (and, since it's pretty simple in this case, to also say "I installed Qt with `brew install qt` as suggested in this tutorial"), and clean up the formatting while you're at it.

Comment: I have to complete a Programming Test for a potential internship, and I must complete it in Pyside in Python 2.7 :/ Will fix the post, thanks!

Comment: OK, if you've already started installing things against the built-in Python 2, you're probably better off sticking with that. It may or may not have been the right decision from a clean start, but installing another 2.7 now when you've already got `pip` and things in `site-packages` is just going to cause major confusion. So never mind that part.

Answer (score 0):

PySide is 4 years out of date and essentially dead, and doesn't work with any Qt later than 4.8. But the instructions you're following (probably also 4 years out of date) tell you to install the latest Qt, which at the moment is 5.10.

To work around this, you need to explicitly install Qt 4.8. You may be able to do this with Homebrew:

```
brew install qt@4.8
```

But I haven't tested whether that works.

Also, Homebrew's Qt package installs as a "keg-only" link by default nowadays. That may not have been true when the old tutorial you're following was written. In which case you may need to follow the instructions given in the output of that `brew install`, which will be something like this:

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/qt/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/pkgconfig
```

If this all sounds like a mess—or if you just don't want to be stuck on Qt 4.8 forever—then you probably don't actually want to use PySide. There are two major alternatives:

- [`PySide2`](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2) was designed by the PySide core devs together with the official Qt company as a replacement for PySide which works with Qt 5 (and, presumably, beyond), and newer versions of OS X (and other platforms) and Python 3, and fixes some problems that couldn't be fixed without a breaking change. This isn't yet in stable 1.0 state, but it has already been used for real projects. (I believe the goal is to start versioning it in sync with Qt itself once it's finished, so the first stable version may be something like 5.11 or 5.12, not 1.0.)
- [`PyQt`](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) is a different library from a separate company. It's working and stable today, but it doesn't have the same license terms as `PySide` and doesn't have direct support from the Qt company. (IIRC, you can get commercial licensing or GPL licensing, but not LGPL—but don't trust me; check it yourself.)

(There is actually a port of PySide to Qt5 by Christian Tismer, but as far as I know he abandoned it a couple years ago to take leadership of the PySide2 project instead, and the old version was left unfinished, so I wouldn't bother searching for that.)

Of course if you're following tutorials for Qt4 and PySide, you'll need to replace those with newer tutorials if you go with Qt5 and PySide2 or PyQt.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! I guess I'll try using PyQt!